# Using acronym inside table

Tags: tables, acronyms

I'm getting an extra empty line at the top of the cell when using an acronym inside a table. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
\acrodef{Test}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}}
Test & \Ac{Test} \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probable that `\Ac` is poorly programmed, in the sense that it starts in vertical mode rather than horizontal mode. You can compensate this by adding `\leavevmode`, `\hspace{0pt)` or `\mbox{}` in front of `Ac`.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}}
Test & \mbox{}\Ac{Test} \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]